# How to do type refinement of an union of two "Exact" objects?

Tags: flowtype

The two possibilities of DateObj seems disjoint to me still, Flow doesn't seem to refine the type on the else branch. How can I make this correctly typed?

```
type DateObj = {| date: string |} | {| dateTime: string |}

export const parseDate = (dateObj: DateObj) => {
  if (dateObj.date) {
    return moment(dateObj.date).toDate()
  } else {
    return moment(dateObj.dateTime).toDate()
  }
}
```

> Flow: property `dateTime`. Property not found in object type
>
> (at the line of the last return statement)

Answer (score 2):

Trying in https://flow.org/try/ helped, it gave me an additional error

```
if (dateObj.date) {
    ^ Sketchy null check. Perhaps you meant to check for null instead of for existence?
```

Fixing this error also solved my original issue

```
if (dateObj.date !== undefined) {
```

Comment: FYI, the sketchy null check warning is part of a project to provide opt-in type-aware linting. It is meant to be off by default, but it was accidentally enabled in flow.org/try.